# Mastering apt-get

Tags: apt

I'd like to learn about `apt-get` so nothing bad can surprise me. I was looking for some tutorials but have found nothing that teaches it carefully including its internals. I found [this](http://maketecheasier.com/become-an-apt-guru/2009/02/24) article but it's insufficient for me.

Where can I learn more (excluding documentation and manual pages)?

*Mastering* here does not mean that I will learn 100 switches of the `apt-get` command but it means that I will learn how it works on some more general level than reading its source code.

Thank you.

Comment: `man apt-get` would be a pretty good place to start...

Comment: @jasonwryan Maybe you learn from it but I use it rather as a manual or reference. I learn rather form something more [cohesive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(linguistics))

Comment: Are you looking to learn more about the entire .deb package system, or simply the apt command Ubuntu uses to interface therewith?

Comment: @Arrdem `apt-get` and `dpkg` are the commands that I use most often. I'm interested in the internals of this system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raphael Hertzog released a [free chapter - "Maintenance and Updates: The Apt Tools"](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/11/15/20-things-to-learn-with-the-free-chapter-of-the-debian-administrators-handbook/) from his book ["Debian Administrator’s Handbook"](http://debian-handbook.info).

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for good online docs you should look at debian docs:

http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html

Also as stated the man pages are mandatory

HTH

Comment: I don't think I've ever read the `dpkg` or `apt-get` man pages in their entirety.  If I had I very much doubt that I would learn what the OP wants to know.  I'd not describe them as mandatory at all.

Comment: IMHO man pages are always mandatory. Except if you own a help forum :-)

Answer (score 2):

`man apt-get` contains detailed information on its internals. You may also want to read `man dpkg`. There is also very good documentation on Debian's package management infrastructure [here](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html).

Answer (score 1):

Well, seeing as you are interested in the actual nuts and bolts of the Debian package system, this is probably the page for you: [From the Debian Docs](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/reference/ch02.en.html)

This also seems like a good introduction: [Presentation on Apt and Dpkg](http://luv.asn.au/overheads/aptitude/aptitude-intro.html)

Of course Wikipedia is also a fabulous source for an overview as always : [Advanced Package Tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool)

The bottom line it seems is that using only "raw" dpkg, it is quite possible to get stuck in RPM-like dependancy hell. dpkg provides only a framework for writing, distributing and executing pre/make/post scripts for installation.

Aptitude or the "Advanced Packaging Tool" provides a layer of abstraction above the dpkg system which allows for more advanced and useful functionality such as dependency and "recommends" resolution.

So by using apt you are far less likely to shoot yourself (and/or your system) in the foot and you will almost never need to muck with dpkg.

Comment: Thank you. I like the paragraph `Usage` from wikipedia article. It would be great if this could be described in more detail.

Comment: `While dpkg performs actions on individual packages, apt tools manage relations (especially dependencies) between them, as well as sourcing and management of higher-level versioning decisions (release tracking and version pinning).`

Comment: The above citation could be explained more in depth somewhere.

Comment: How/why? That statement is definitional. Dpkg provides an environment for installing __arbitrary__ packages. The point of building the Apt system was to solve version-specific dependency and resource location problems by centralizing everything to the package repos.